# PHP externel file contact form that display a message after redirect to the form page

Tags: php, forms, contact-form

I have a problem because i have 2 different file for a contact form but i need that after the form submit and the consecutive redirect to email.php then the return to form.php it will display a variable created inside email.php (the result of the form). I think that i could do this by SESSION or cookie but i don't think this is the best way so can somebody help me to print `$formResult` inside form.php?

**form.php**

```
<form id="contact-form" method="POST" action="email.php">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="contact-name">Name</label>
        <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" id="contact-textarea" placeholder="Name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
         <label class="sr-only" for="contact-email">Email address</label>
         <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="contact-email" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
         <label class="sr-only" for="contact-message">Message</label>
         <textarea name="message" id="contact-message" class="form-control" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn contact-submit">Send message</button>
</form>
```

**email.php**

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $formName = $_POST['name'];
    $formEmail = $_POST['email'];
    $formMessage = $_POST['message'];

    $formBody = "From: $formName\nE-Mail: $formEmail\nMessage:\n$formMessage";
    $formTo = "myemail@gmail.com";
    $formSubject = 'Message from mysite';

    if (mail ($formTo, $formSubject, $formBody)) {
        $formResult = '<div class="alert alert-success"><span>Message sent, thank You!</span></div>';
    } else {
        $formResult = '<div class="alert alert-error"><span>Sorry there was an error. Please try again later.</span></div>';
    }

    header("location: form.php");

}
```

Comment: Errr.... `echo $formResult;` ?

Comment: @Fred-ii- only works in `email.php` not the other file.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- oh c'mon, error reporting is so 2010, people don't want to read about their errors in this day and age, they want psychic assistance! I often ask the man over the road why my colleague at work always arrives late (because it would be silly to ask my colleague directly!)

Comment: @Martin So I shouldn't tell anyone anymore to check for errors as to why their code doesn't work then. Ok, I won't then.

Comment: @Fred-ii- but when you do, I'll always be +1'ing those comments :-D

Comment: But this question doesn't have anything to do with error reporting...

Comment: @Mikey you don't know what's in the box until you look....

Comment: @Martin TBH, I'm kind of growing tired these days of constantly being one out of 5 guys to have them figure out why code fails. I think I'll take a break for a while and have people ping me when they have real problems (wink).

Comment: No, it's about how to get one value from one page to another page.

Comment: @Fred-ii- perhaps take a challenge of only touching bounty questions or only questions asked by people above a certain rep (which I would vaguely assume means they'd be using the correct API and be knowledgable of error checking etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change **email.php** to

```
session_start();

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $formName = $_POST['name'];
    $formEmail = $_POST['email'];
    $formMessage = $_POST['message'];

    $formBody = "From: $formName\nE-Mail: $formEmail\nMessage:\n$formMessage";
    $formTo = "myemail@gmail.com";
    $formSubject = 'Message from mysite';

    mail ($formTo, $formSubject, $formBody);

    if (mail ($formTo, $formSubject, $formBody)) {
        $_SESSION['alert'] = '<div class="alert alert-success"><span>Message sent, thank You!</span></div>'; // changed
    } else {
        $_SESSION['alert'] = '<div class="alert alert-error"><span>Sorry there was an error. Please try again later.</span></div>'; // changed
    }

    header("location: form.php");

}
```

In your **form.php**, print the session variable if it exist. After showing it, remove the session.

```
<?php session_start() ?>

<?php 
if (isset($_SESSION['alert'])) {
    echo $_SESSION['alert'];
    unset($_SESSION['alert']);
} 
?>

<form id="contact-form" method="POST" action="email.php">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="contact-name">Name</label>
        <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" id="contact-textarea" placeholder="Name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
         <label class="sr-only" for="contact-email">Email address</label>
         <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="contact-email" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
         <label class="sr-only" for="contact-message">Message</label>
         <textarea name="message" id="contact-message" class="form-control" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn contact-submit">Send message</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Why should the OP try this? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: <?= isset($_SESSION['alert']) ? echo $_SESSION['alert'] : '' ?> give me an error but yeah no problems it works with normal php sintax so THANK YOU.

Answer (score 1):

You are thinking the right way, you can use `sessions` to print the message after submitting.

You need to start the session first, so put in `email.php`, under the `<?php` this line:

```
session_start();
```

Then replace in `email.php` the following variable `$formResult` to `$_SESSION["formResult"]`

Now put in `form.php` this code:

```
<?php
session_start(); # This line must always on top of your file under the '<?php'
isset($_SESSION["formResult"])) {
    echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION["formResult"]);

    # Now remove the session :)
    unset($_SESSION["formResult"]);
}
?>
```

Comment: thank you for "htmlspecialchars" precisation  that other answer does not have. (+1)

Comment: You're welcome ^^. @paolobasso It's good to know you need to escape input and output if you are using PHP in your site

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can implement this is using url variables so that way you don't need sessions or cookies, for instance

**form.php**

```
<?php
// define here an array of messages
$results = array(
    1 => '<div class="alert alert-success"><span>Message sent, thank You!</span></div>',
    2 => '<div class="alert alert-error"><span>Sorry there was an error. Please try again later.</span></div>',
);

if(isset($_GET['result']) && isset($results[$_GET['result']]))
{
   echo $results[$_GET['result']];
}

?>

<form id="contact-form" method="POST" action="email.php">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="contact-name">Name</label>
        <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" id="contact-textarea" placeholder="Name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
         <label class="sr-only" for="contact-email">Email address</label>
         <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="contact-email" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
         <label class="sr-only" for="contact-message">Message</label>
         <textarea name="message" id="contact-message" class="form-control" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn contact-submit">Send message</button>
</form>
```

**email.php**

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $formName = $_POST['name'];
    $formEmail = $_POST['email'];
    $formMessage = $_POST['message'];

    $formBody = "From: $formName\nE-Mail: $formEmail\nMessage:\n$formMessage";
    $formTo = "myemail@gmail.com";
    $formSubject = 'Message from mysite';

    if (mail ($formTo, $formSubject, $formBody))
    {
        $formResult = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        $formResult = 2;
    }

    header("location: form.php?result=$formResult");

}
```